# jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i want to validate phone number.max 10 numbers.

***this is my php file coding***

```
<div id="sign_up">
    <h4><?php 
         if($_REQUEST['page']=='login' && $_REQUEST['page1']=='sign_up')
        {
            _e(REGISTRATION_NOW_TEXT);
        }else
        {
            _e(REGISTRATION_NOW_TEXT);
        }
         ?></h4>

 <?php
 if ( $_REQUEST['emsg']==1)
 {
    echo "<p class=\"error_msg_fix\"> ".EMAIL_USERNAME_EXIST_MSG." </p>";
 }
 ?> 

<div class="login_content">
<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('ptthemes_reg_page_content'));?>
</div>


<div class="registration_form_box">

 <form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ).'/?page=login&amp;action=register'; ?>" method="post">

 <input type="hidden" name="reg_redirect_link" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>" />     
  <p class="note"><span class="indicates">*</span> <?php _e(INDICATES_MANDATORY_FIELDS_TEXT);?></p>
  <h5 class="rfh"><?php _e(PERSONAL_INFO_TEXT);?> </h5> 

<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label><?php _e(EMAIL_TEXT) ?><span class="indicates">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_email)); ?>" size="25" />
    <div id="reg_passmail">
      <?php _e(REGISTRATION_MESSAGE) ?>
    </div>
    <span id="user_emailInfo"></span>
</div>



<div class="row_spacer_registration clearfix" >
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(FIRST_NAME_TEXT) ?>
  <span class="indicates">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="user_fname" id="user_fname" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_fname)); ?>" size="25"  />
   <span id="user_fnameInfo"></span>
</div>
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(LAST_NAME_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_lname" id="user_lname" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_lname)); ?>" size="25"  />
</div>

</div> 

 <div class="row_spacer_registration clearfix" >
<h5 ><?php _e(ADD_INFO_TEXT);?> </h5>
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(ADDRESS1_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_add1" id="user_add1" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_add1)); ?>" size="25" />
</div>
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(ADDRESS2_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_add2" id="user_add2" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_add2)); ?>" size="25" />
</div>
</div>


<div class="row_spacer_registration clearfix" >
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(CITY_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_city" id="user_city" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_city)); ?>" size="25" />
</div>
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(STATE_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_state" id="user_state" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_state)); ?>" size="25" />
</div>
</div>


<div class="row_spacer_registration clearfix" >
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(COUNTRY_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_country" id="user_country" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_country)); ?>" size="25" />
 </div>
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(POSTAL_CODE_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_postalcode" id="user_postalcode" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_postalcode)); ?>" size="25" />
</div>
</div>


<?php do_action('register_form'); ?>

<div class="fix"></div>
<h5><?php _e(OTHER_INFO_TEXT) ?></h5>
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(YR_WEBSITE_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_web" id="user_web" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_web)); ?>" size="25" />
</div>
 <div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(PHONE_NUMBER_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_phone" id="user_phone" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_phone)); ?>" size="25" />
</div>
<div class="form_row clearfix">
  <label>
  <?php _e(TWITTER_TEXT) ?>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="user_twitter" id="user_twitter" class="textfield" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_twitter)); ?>" size="25" />
</div>
<!-- <a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return chk_form_reg();" class="highlight_button fr " >Register Now </a>-->

<input type="submit" name="registernow" value="<?php _e(REGISTER_NOW_TEXT);?>" class="btn_input_highlight btn_spacer" />
```

**this is my .js file code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

////////////LOGIN FORM START

//global vars

    var loginform = $("#loginform");

    var user_login = $("#user_login");

    var user_loginInfo = $("#user_loginInfo");

    var user_pass = $("#user_pass");

    var user_passInfo = $("#user_passInfo");



    //On blur

    user_login.blur(validate_user_login);

    user_pass.blur(validate_user_pass);



    //On key press

    user_login.keyup(validate_user_login);

    user_pass.keyup(validate_user_pass);



    //On Submitting

    loginform.submit(function(){

        if(validate_user_login() & validate_user_pass())

            return true

        else

            return false;

    });

////////////LOGIN FORM END



////////////REGISTRATION FORM START

    var registerform = $("#registerform");

    var user_login1reg = $("#user_login1reg");

    var user_login1regInfo = $("#user_login1regInfo");

    var user_email = $("#user_email");

    var user_emailInfo = $("#user_emailInfo");

    var user_fname = $("#user_fname");

    var user_fnameInfo = $("#user_fnameInfo");



        //On blur

    user_login1reg.blur(validate_user_login1reg);

    user_email.blur(validate_user_email);

    user_fname.blur(validate_user_fname);



    //On key press

    user_login1reg.keyup(validate_user_login1reg);

    user_email.keyup(validate_user_email);

    user_fname.keyup(validate_user_fname);



    //On Submitting

    registerform.submit(function(){

        if(validate_user_login1reg() & validate_user_email() & validate_user_fname())

            return true

        else

            return false;

    });



////////////REGISTRATION FORM END

    //validation functions

    function validate_user_login()

    {

                var input=$("#your-name").val();
        var check=0;
        if(input==''){
                       check=1;
               }
        if(input.indexOf("0") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("1") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("2") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("3") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("4") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("5") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("6") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("7") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("8") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("9") != -1){
            check=1;
        }

    if(check==1){

            user_login.addClass("error");

            user_loginInfo.text("Please Enter Username");

            user_loginInfo.addClass("message_error2");

            return false;

        }

        else{

            user_login.removeClass("error");

            user_loginInfo.text("");

            user_loginInfo.removeClass("message_error2");

            return true;

        }

    }

    function validate_user_pass()

    {

        if($("#user_pass").val() == '')

        {

            user_pass.addClass("error");

            user_passInfo.text("Please Enter Password");

            user_passInfo.addClass("message_error2");

            return false;

        }

        else{

            user_pass.removeClass("error");

            user_passInfo.text("");

            user_passInfo.removeClass("message_error2");

            return true;

        }

    }





    function validate_user_login1reg()

    {

        if($("#user_login1reg").val() == '')

        {

            user_login1reg.addClass("error");

            user_login1regInfo.text("Please Enter Username");

            user_login1regInfo.addClass("message_error2");

            return false;

        }

        else{

            user_login1reg.removeClass("error");

            user_login1regInfo.text("");

            user_login1regInfo.removeClass("message_error2");

            return true;

        }

    }



    function validate_user_fname()

    {

        var input=$("#your-name").val();
        var check=0;
        if(input==''){
                       check=1;
               }
        if(input.indexOf("0") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("1") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("2") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("3") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("4") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("5") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("6") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("7") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("8") != -1){
            check=1;
        }
        if(input.indexOf("9") != -1){
            check=1;
        }

        if(check==1){

            user_fname.addClass("error");

            user_fnameInfo.text("Please Enter First Name");

            user_fnameInfo.addClass("message_error2");

            return false;

        }

        else{

            user_fname.removeClass("error");

            user_fnameInfo.text("");

            user_fnameInfo.removeClass("message_error2");

            return true;

        }

    }

    // phone validate
    //function validate_user_phone()
    //{
    var regEx = new RegExp("/[0-9]/");

    $("#user_phone").bind("submit", function() {

    if ($("#user_phone").val().length != 10 && !$("#user_phone").val().match(regEx)) {
        $("#user_phone").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;
    }
});

    //}


    function validate_user_email()

    {

        var isvalidemailflag = 0;

        if($("#user_email").val() == '')

        {

            isvalidemailflag = 1;

        }else

        if($("#user_email").val() != '')

        {

            var a = $("#user_email").val();

            var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

            //if it's valid email

            if(filter.test(a)){

                isvalidemailflag = 0;

            }else{

                isvalidemailflag = 1;   

            }

        }

        if(isvalidemailflag)

        {

            user_email.addClass("error");

            user_emailInfo.text("Please Enter valid E-mail");

            user_emailInfo.addClass("message_error2");

            return false;

        }else

        {

            user_email.removeClass("error");

            user_emailInfo.text("");

            user_emailInfo.removeClass("message_error");

            return true;

        }



    }



});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking questions, please only post the minimal amount of code required, so that we don't have to wade through pages and pages of code to find the single line you're referring to.

Comment: Have you considered using a mask plugin instead?

Comment: can you help me to do this :(

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be in your regular expression. Try something like this:

> "/^[0-9]+$/"

to ensure there are only numbers in the string.

Comment: can you help me to do this :(

Comment: Sure. just replace [code] var regEx = new RegExp("/[0-9]/"); [/code] with [code] var regEx = new RegExp("/^[0-9]+$/"); [/code]

Comment: i couldn't get it. can i have your email please.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a TON of time and hassle.  Use one that's already done and checked.  Here's my favorite:

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/